# Oauth refresh token revoke vs delete

Tags: oauth, refresh-token, revoke-token

Can someone explain me why we revoke refresh token instead of simply delete them? I'm trying to understand in which case deletion could cause issue.

Comment: Deleting still leaves it "open" on the server side.  Revoking removes it from the server side.  Lets say you had an active token, and someone, somehow found it -- They can now use it to log in, even if you "delete" it from your storage.  Revoking then deleting is always the safest option.